# How to read a particular field from json data?

Tags: python, json

I want to retrieve `"text:"` field from the JSON data. How can I do that in python?

```
{ 
   "contributors":null,
   "truncated":false,
   "text":"A perfect gift to yourself this new year! #celiac #glutenfree ",
   "in_reply_to_status_id":null,
   "id":418468308673773568,
   "favorite_count":0,
}
```

Comment: Please post the code you've tried so far and the errors you encountered (there is a json module in Python to do that).

Answer (score 2):

Python includes the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#module-json) module which allows you to parse a JSON string directly to a Python dictionary.

```
import json
dic = json.loads(json_str)
```

You can now access the value with `dic['key']`. In your case `dic['text']`.

Please keep in mind that a valid [JSON](https://json.org/) format is necessary.
You have to remove the `','` at the end of `"favorite_count":0,`.

Comment: hey i got this error : "ValueError: Trailing data".